# Did Nightwatch only recruit among station security?

Tags: babylon-5

In *Babylon 5* seasons 2-3 (maybe further, but that's as far as I've got), the sinister Orwellian organisation known as 'Nightwatch' is established as a sort of secret police, a way for Clark and Minipax to keep a network of spies on the station.

In its early appearances, as far as I remember, the organisation was recruiting all sorts of people, ordinary citizens; Garibaldi's second Zack was one of the few security personnel who joined. But by the time of the pivotal episode "Point of No Return", it seems that Nightwatch is primarily based in security, and at the end of the episode Sheridan and co

> seemingly neutralise Nightwatch just by drawing all the Nightwatch *security* personnel into one place.

Am I remembering wrongly and Nightwatch was always recruiting mostly or only among station security? If not, what happened to all its other members by the time of "Point of No Return"?

Comment: When you say that you remember them recruiting civilians, is that based on their attire? Some piece of dialogue?

Comment: @Thunderforge I just got the idea that Nightwatch was a whole mixed bag of people, and essentially anyone could potentially be one of them (a la Orwell's Thought Police). And yes, pretty sure they weren't all in uniform. But I haven't rewatched the earlier episodes, so this is more based on an impression than definite facts.

Comment: Hey, you'd be surprised what I would do for an extra hundred space credits a month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There's more of them.**  It's just that the ones in security are in the most obvious position to do immediate harm.

In just a few more episodes, you will watch *Ceremonies of Light and Dark* in which...

> ... the leftovers of Nightwatch that have been in hiding on the station band together for a hostage gambit, trying to force the Sheridan gang to surrender after Nightwatch have well and truly lost any hold on the station.

I don't think much more is detailed... my hunch is that a majority of the Nightwatch civilians that were willing became security recruits and were rounded up in short order in the same movement Sheridan kicked the rest of the station.  If there were any left after the later episode, they kept their mouths shut about it and laid low.

Answer (score 3):

### The Nightwatch also recruited from the Earth Corps military stationed on the ship

**Don't use any of these links until you're done watching, Rand!**

Along with Pierce Macabee's successful recruitment of station security officers, the Nightwatch also targeted Earthforce marines stationed on the ship.  [Boggs](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Boggs) and [his sniper friend](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Sniper_(Ceremonies_of_Light_and_Dark)) were two such recruits.